# Cassandra aggregate function "first_row"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, udf

I know, that Cassandra allows to `GROUP BY` and can run `UDF` on that data.

Is there any default function to get the first row of each aggregated set?

*(How)* Can I stop processing data and return result from my UDF immediately (E.G. After 1 or few rows processed)?

Now I'm using `... COUNT(1) ...` as workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy You fon't need any UDF. It works as described out of the box.

Jusr `GROUP BY`  fields you need.